# Custom Form Field not working in Windows environment

Tags: form-fields-types, custom-field

My attempt is to re-build the example here:
https://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_custom_form_field_type

Somehow, Joomla doesn't see the `City.php` file in administrator/components/com_testing/models/fields.
Even when I force a syntax error inside the `City.php` file (e.g. deleting an `;` at the end of a line), no error is displayed. So I am assuming the `City.php` file isn't even included.

I tried to include the new field path via `addfieldpath` in `fieldset`-definition and also with `JForm::addFieldPath(JPATH_COMPONENT . '/models/fields');` in the model's `getForm`-function.
Nothing worked so far.

The output is a text input field, which I do not want.

Here is my source code:

`City.php` file is equivalent to the one in the link above.

`administrator/components/com_testing/models/forms/testing.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<form>
    <fieldset addfieldpath="/administrator/components/com_testing/models/fields">
        <field
            name="testingfield"
            type="City"
            multiple="true"
            size="7"
            label="Testinglabel">
                    <option value="A">A</option>
                    <option value="B">B</option>
                    <option value="C">C</option>
                    <option value="D">D</option>
                    <option value="E">E</option>
                    <option value="F">F</option>
                    <option value="G">G</option>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Rename your file name to lower case city.php

Comment: Maybe your development machine is Windows (which has case insensitive file names) and everything works there but you deploy to Linux (case sensitive file names) and it fails? Keep your names lowercase (as @Nagarjun mentioned)

Answer (score 2):

If you field is in the administrator, you want to use this include path:
`JFormHelper::addFieldPath(JPATH_COMPONENT_ADMINISTRATOR.'/models/fields');`

---

Oh and you want that filename to be lowercase (as commented under the question). Basically, every file in Joomla should be lowercase.

The Windows file system is not case sensitive, while Linux is.

Change `City.php` to `city.php`.

Answer (score 1):

Set the type to city in lowercase, and if it doesn't still work try adding addfieldpath to the field as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<form>
    <fieldset>
        <field
            addfieldpath="/administrator/components/com_testing/models/fields"
            name="testingfield"
            type="City"
            multiple="true"
            size="7"
            label="Testinglabel">
                    <option value="A">A</option>
                    <option value="B">B</option>
                    <option value="C">C</option>
                    <option value="D">D</option>
                    <option value="E">E</option>
                    <option value="F">F</option>
                    <option value="G">G</option>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

as in some cases the fieldset path cannot be accessed.

Also check the FormField file that you are using and match the cases as in the example file.

In one case I have faced an issue the formfield doesn't not load, so also try to make a same file with some other type eg : replace city with Example and do not forget to match the case.

Hope this helps.